# Missing 'build' directory in Debian 10.6

Tags: debian, make

I'm trying to compile https://github.com/betolj/ndpi-netfilter on Debian Buster 10.6.

In short I get this error:

```
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.19.0-11-cloud-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

These are the steps I have done:

```
apt install libtool libpcap-dev iptables-dev
apt install conntrack libnetfilter-conntrack-dev
cd /home/admin
git clone https://github.com/betolj/ndpi-netfilter
cd ndpi-netfilter
tar -xvzf nDPI.tar.gz
cd nDPI
./autogen.sh
cd ..
NDPI_PATH=/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/nDPI make
```

And I get this error:

```
make -C ipt
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/ipt'
if test -d ndpi_cpy; then \
    cp /home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/nDPI/src/* ndpi_cpy -R; \
else \
    mkdir ndpi_cpy; \
    cp /home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/nDPI/src/* ndpi_cpy -R; \
fi
make libxt_ndpi.so
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/ipt'
make[2]: 'libxt_ndpi.so' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/ipt'
rm -r ndpi_cpy
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/ipt'
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/src'
if test -d ndpi_cpy; then \
    cp /home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/nDPI/src/* ndpi_cpy -R; \
else \
    mkdir ndpi_cpy; \
    cp /home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/nDPI/src/* ndpi_cpy -R; \
fi
cp ndpi_cpy/../../nDPI-patch/src/* ndpi_cpy/ -R;
cp ndpi_cpy/lib/third_party/src/*.c ndpi_cpy/lib -R;
cp ndpi_cpy/lib/third_party/include/*.h ndpi_cpy/lib -R;
cp ndpi_cpy/lib/third_party/include/*.h ndpi_cpy/include -R;
sed -i "s/^\s*void ndpi_free_flow/\/\/void ndpi_free_flow/" ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_api.h;
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-11-cloud-amd64/build M=$PWD;
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/src'
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.19.0-11-cloud-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/ndpi-netfilter/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2
```

What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the kernel headers (which include the module build infrastructure):

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```